# Column-wise element selection in R

Tags: r

I need to select elements of a dataframe using the row indices, as stored in a vector. In other words, I have a vector or length equal to the number of columns in a data frame, and that vector contains the row numbers of the elements I need to extract (one element per column, in order).

How would I go about doing this?

Example:

```r
vec <- c(1,2,1)
df <- data.frame(matrix(1:6, ncol = 3, nrow = 2))
```

That would look like this:

```
  X1 X2 X3
1  1  3  5
2  2  4  6
```

And I would need to get elements (1,4,5) using the indices from vec = 1,2,1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use :

```
df[cbind(vec, 1:ncol(df))]
#[1] 1 4 5
```

Using `cbind`, we create a row and column index to subset values from `df`.

```
cbind(vec, 1:ncol(df))
      vec  
#[1,]   1 1
#[2,]   2 2
#[3,]   1 3
```

Using this matrix, we subset values from (row 1, column1), (row2, column2) and row(1, column3).

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Would you mind explaining how does it work?

Comment: Yup, I had no idea we could provide sets of pairs of values in a matrix/df. I had done extensive subsetting using pairs of vectors, never a matrix! Thanks